# Problem moving a shape off partly off screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have recently started migrating an Android XML app to Jetpack Compose. As I have not used compose prior to this I still trying to get familiar to it.

The UI I have designed for the application incorporates circles that are partially cur off screen :
[image: Base UI of with partially cut off circles]

When trying to replicate this inside compose I have been able to make the circle but I can't quite position it without morphing the shape. Here is what I have in compose:
[image: Compose version of the UI]

Here is the code for the circle :

```
Box(
            Modifier
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    spotColor = Color(0x40000000),
                    ambientColor = Color(0x40000000),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 355.dp)
                )
                .padding(
                    end = 0.dp, // Ignore this as it was a placeholder while testing                     )
                .width(355.dp)
                .height(355.dp)
                .background(
                    color = Color(0xA300C2FF),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        size = 355.dp
                    ),
                )
        )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Modifier.offset or Modifier.graphicsLayer to move a Composable.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun OffsetSample() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            // Alternative 1
            .graphicsLayer {
                translationX = -355.dp.toPx() / 2
            }
            // Alternative 2
//            .offset((-355).dp / 2)
            .shadow(
                elevation = 4.dp,
                spotColor = Color(0x40000000),
                ambientColor = Color(0x40000000),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 355.dp)
            )

            .width(355.dp)
            .height(355.dp)

            .background(
                color = Color(0xA300C2FF),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                    size = 355.dp
                ),
            )
    )
}
```

Also you can draw both Circles as

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun OffsetSample2() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .padding(top =  30.dp)
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationX = -355.dp.toPx() / 2
                }
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    spotColor = Color(0x40000000),
                    ambientColor = Color(0x40000000),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 355.dp)
                )

                .width(355.dp)
                .height(355.dp)

                .background(
                    color = Color(0xA300C2FF),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        size = 355.dp
                    ),
                )
        )

        Box(
            Modifier
                .padding(bottom =  30.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationX = 355.dp.toPx() / 2
                }
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    spotColor = Color(0x40000000),
                    ambientColor = Color(0x40000000),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 355.dp)
                )

                .width(355.dp)
                .height(355.dp)

                .background(
                    color = Color(0xA300C2FF),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        size = 355.dp
                    ),
                )
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

### Edit

Shadow as other modifiers also is moved when it's placed after offset or graphicsLayer.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun OffsetSample3() {
   Column {

       Box(
           Modifier
               .graphicsLayer {
                   translationX = -355.dp.toPx() / 2
               }
               .shadow(
                   elevation = 8.dp,
                   spotColor = Color(0x40000000),
                   ambientColor = Color(0x40000000),
                   shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 355.dp)
               )
               .width(355.dp)
               .height(355.dp)

               .background(
                   color = Color(0xA300C2FF),
                   shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                       size = 355.dp
                   ),
               )
       )
       Box(
           Modifier
               .shadow(
                   elevation = 8.dp,
                   spotColor = Color(0x40000000),
                   ambientColor = Color(0x40000000),
                   shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 355.dp)
               )
               .graphicsLayer {
                   translationX = -355.dp.toPx() / 2
               }

               .width(355.dp)
               .height(355.dp)

               .background(
                   color = Color(0xA300C2FF),
                   shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                       size = 355.dp
                   ),
               )
       )
   }
}
```

Second one doesn't move shadow and shadows in Jetpack Compose are similar to shapes assigned that are drawn with spot and ambient color and with some blur.

[image]

Without shadow clip in second one

[image]

Comment: This works for moving the shape itself but the shadow is left behind, is there a way to fix that? https://imgur.com/tjHedcq (Correct image)

Comment: It doesn't leave shadow behind. Any Modifier, for instance shadow, border, background, clickable, assigned after Modifier.offset or Modifier graphicsLayer is moved. You can verify it by changing order of  Modifier.graphicsLayer and shadow to see how it will look when shadow is not moved. The reason you experience is how shadows drawn in jetpack Compose. They are drawn as a shape with some blur. You need to implement custom shadows for transparent backgrdouns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75951945/5457853 You can refere this answer how shadow works, or simply try it in a Composable with no background to see how it's drawn

Comment: Also in images, shadow clips, if i set clip=false in second image it would be drawing it without clipping

Comment: You can pick same non-transparent color to use default shadow modifier or implement your own shadow using frameworkPaint for circles. But for input section i think you should implement your own shadow.